# Is there a html way to not load some html only if screen has min-width?

Tags: html, responsive-design

In the paradigm of responsive design it's easy to hide stuff via css like this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
    #flash {
    display:none;
}
```

Is there a way not to load the div with id="flash" without javascript, flash or server site languages? The reason for me of not loading the flash part is that i dont want mobile devices to load it...

HTML:

```
<div id="flash">
   <flashgallerystuff></>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use lack of javascript to hide an element, but you could take a 'progressive enhancement' type approach and use javascript to *insert* the div in question. That way the div is never present for users without javascript.

Another, similar approach, is to give the body tag a default class of, eg. 'no-js', which you remove on pageload with javascript (so browsers without js will have that class on their body tags). Then you can use that class in the CSS to set a default of 'display:none' for your 'flash' div:

`.no-js #flash { display: none }`

Answer (score 1):

The only possible way (without using javascript) is to use separate pages for your normal and mobile version of the web site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you elaborate it a bit more? Where would you do the screen detection and how does that look like?

Comment: Screen resolution detection is possible with javascript, but you want to avoid using this approach, so you just need to create a mobile version of the html page with most common dimensions, let`s say 400px width, (almost) no images, bigger font size (to be easier to read). However, if you want automatic detection of the user`s browser/device and automatic redirection to the mobile version page, you need to use javascript and/or server side detection script, PHP for example.
See here for javascript detection http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml